# Eclipse has multiple copies of same Android Device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I've been programming for Android devices for some time now and just recently came across this:[image: Multiple devices with same name in Eclipse..]

There is a single one in the list online, but I can't run/debug my programs because it reports "ADB rejected install command with: device offline" since every other device has the same ID.

A reset fixes this, but is there any other options? Why is this happening?

Comment: Never came up with an answer for this one, Just restart it and it works..

Comment: ya.Just faced this issue.so executed command adb kill-server and restared eclipse.Didnt get the reason for this!!

Answer (score 11):

Exit eclipse, kill adb and restart eclipse

Comment: Jayesh, esteve has already explained how to fix this. What he is asking is why does this happen. He looking for expertise on the subject rather than a quick solution.

Comment: You can do `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` and not have to restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the issue is often with a bad cable or connection. Try and insert it into another USB slot or try with a different cable, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remind myself how to call the commands, so I thought I'd write an answer for other people that don't remember how.

1. Find the location of `adb.exe`.
2. Open up command prompt.
3. In command line, change the directory to the directory from step 1.

   - For me, the command and directory is: `cd C:\ADT\sdk\platform-tools`
4. Run: `adb kill-server` from the command prompt
5. Run: `adb start-server` from the command prompt

Credits to [Squeazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633940/squeazer) for the commands.