# Eclipse detecting the same device multiple times

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

I am facing a strange problem. The eclipse is deteting the same device multiple times and thus is unable to run the project showing error as :

```
Failed to install MetRoute.apk on device 'EC21BF384504FC4E': adb rejected install command with: more than one device
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device
Launch canceled!
```

See This image:

[image]

I tried to take help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963276/eclipse-has-multiple-copies-of-same-android-device) question but no help after following the process. Does anyone have any other solution.?

Comment: If you close Eclipse and run adb devices in command line, does it display multiple devices? Also, in command line, have you tried: adb kill-server then adb start-server then adb usb and start Eclipse again?

Comment: Close the `adb`. Close eclipse. Delete all the processes `adb` is running under task manager. Restart eclipse. Run `adb` again.

Comment: @Melq  Yes I have tried all that. I saw that question to solve it, it tried and it didnt work. So I posted my ques.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352360/android-within-android-device-chooser-the-same-device-shows-up-several-times

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**update : It is not needed to restart/close Eclipse**

As told in comments by Ved Praksh, the solution is:

Exit Eclipse

End all adb processes from task manager as well.. Then:

In cmd, adb kill-server --> adb start-server --> adb devices

Then restart eclipse.

Most probably it will show only one device this time.

Answer (score 2):

In windows start task manager >>> Processes Tab >>> Right click `adb.exe*32` >>> End Process and Press End Process on the dialog box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
./adb devices (This should show your device exactly once)
```

and it should work.

And also restart Eclipse after this.

Answer (score 0):

Reset adb in eclipse,If the problem persists it may be caused due to some hardware related issues with the usb port or your cable.
try using another cable/port/device and check whether the issue is solved.