# com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device

Tags: android, adb

how to kill and start adb in window 8. i did in linux but do not have any idea in window 8 b'coz i am getting error of
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device. i restart my eclipse , changed my port but it is no working.

Comment: its stop from the task manager-> services -> find adb.exe and end process. and then after u try to run app its automatic start ADB when 0 to 10 process is completed.

Answer (score 17):

just simple delete the adb.exe file running in your Task Manager

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is formed a bit differently, but the exception is the same so if you're facing the same problem I was then refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680658/eclipse-detecting-the-same-device-multiple-times). Worked for me.

Actually all I had to do was to exit Eclipse and then end adb.exe in Task Manager. Start Eclipse again and voilà, showing only the one device as it should.

Answer (score 2):

You can open comand line, go to sdk/platform-tools folder
(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools - my path)
and run:
adb kill-server

adb start-server

Same answer if you receive "Offline Device"

Comment: After upgrading my old Android studio to 2.1.1 I got this error  and this answer solved  the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just look at the image, Chuck thanks for help!