# Getting “com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device” Exception?

Tags: android, exception, adt

When I run application it show me 
"com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device" Exception and
"Launch error: adb rejected command: more than one device".

Adt detects my two devices with the following names:

memo-memo-0123456789ABCDEF and 0123456789ABCDEF

Any body have any idea why this is occurring and how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem recently. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680658/eclipse-detecting-the-same-device-multiple-times). Worked for me.

Actually all I had to do was to exit Eclipse and then end *adb.exe* in Task Manager. Start Eclipse again and *voilà*, showing only the one device as it should.